# Is there something in ruby similar to perlform?

Tags: ruby

With [perlform](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlform.html) , I was able to format console output like this:

```
#Print report    
$~ = 'REPORT';
$^ = 'REPORT_TOP';
write ;

# Specify format
format REPORT_TOP =
Charge Code   Hours    Description
============= ======== ===============================================
.

format REPORT =
@<<<<<<<<<<<< @<<<<<<< @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
$reportChargeCode, $reportHours, $reportDescription
.
```

Is there a way in ruby to do the same thing?

Edit:

I have a loop that sums up the reportHours for each reportChargeCode stored in a hash. The desired output would look something like:

```
Charge Code   Hours    Description
============= ======== ===============================================
CS5510        2.2575   hw13
ECE3710       5.678333 duck hunt game
```

Comment: It's not clear (to me anyway) what the above code achieves. Could you explain the desired behaviour and output?

Comment: I think formatr will do the job for me, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [FormatR](http://formatr.rubyforge.org/) gem:

```
require "formatr"
include FormatR

# Specify format
report_top = <<DOT
Charge Code   Hours    Description
============= ======== ===============================================
DOT

report = <<DOT
@<<<<<<<<<<<< @<<<<<<< @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
reportChargeCode, reportHours, reportDescription
DOT

body_fmt = Format.new (report_top, report)

body_fmt.setPageLength(10)
num = 1

Reaports.each do |(reportChargeCode, reportHours, reportDescription)|
    body_fmt.printFormat(binding)
end
```